# trying to setup connexion.AioHttpApp() with aiohttp-cors for async routes fails

Tags: python, asynchronous, cors, event-loop, connexion

I'm trying to convert an existing web app that uses `connexion` and `CORS`
to be able to handle async routes.

(calling the async function directly from within an event-loop work fine)

connexion is configured as follows:

```
connexion = {extras = ["aiohttp_swagger"],version = "*"}.
```

```py
app = connexion.AioHttpApp(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
app.add_api('swagger.yaml')
cors = aiohttp_cors.setup(app)
```

I simply want connexion to run in async mode and to be able to handle async routes.

The current cors setup returns

> 'AioHttpApp' object has no attribute 'router'

Answer (score 1):

You must use `app.app`

```py
app = connexion.AioHttpApp(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
app.add_api('swagger.yaml')
cors = aiohttp_cors.setup(app.app)
```